# What happens when you mix then/catch with await in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

What happens if you mix then/catch and await for Promises in Javascript?

```js
await thisReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => /* do something */)
  .catch(() => /* do something */);
```

- Does it await the Promise *twice*? Once for the `await` and once for the `then` callback?
- Does `then` return a new Promise or is it exactly the same as the function returns?
- The `await` will resolve after `then`, but are they resolved at the same time or is there a tiny delay between?

What is returned in this case and why?:

```js
const awaitResult = await thisReturnsAPromise() // returns a Promise<number>
  .then((thenResult) => /* do something */)
  .catch(() => /* do something */);
```

It is clear that it is not ideal to mix the approaches so the question is what happens when you do.

Comment: "*Does then return a new `Promise`?*" - yes. So there's 3 promises in your code: one returned by `thisReturnsAPromise()`, one returned by `.then()`, one returned by `.catch()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here `await` works as if we were promise chaining (kind of)

Example:

```
async function test() {
    let result = await Promise.resolve(5).then((data) => {
        console.log('then: ', data);
        return 10;
    })
    console.log('await:', result);
}

test();

[LOG]: "then: ",  5 
[LOG]: "await:",  10
```

Basically, `await` returns the fulfillment value of the promise or thenable object, or, if the expression is not thenable, the expression's own value. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#return_value)). In the example, we can see that `await` returned `10` due to `then` returning a promise that fulfills to `10`